# Open an xml file that is included in the project

Tags: testing

I added an XML file to a directory that i have in the test project.

How can i access it from the test code?

Comment: Which environment? Which test framework? Which programming language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention what language or IDE you're using, but here is what I've done with C# in Visual Studio:

1. Add your XML files to the Unit Test project (create a new folder for your test files).
2. Go to Test -> Edit Test Settings
3. Click on Deployment
4. Check the box "Enable Deployment" and add the directory you created in step one.
5. In the unit test:

   string testxml = File.ReadAllText("test.xml")